# How to fix setState not updating in react context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am running into an issue where my context is not getting updated when I try to update it through a react hook. I have posted the code below and feel like I may be missing one slight blip.

**appContext.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { ICreateContext } from "../types/generics"

export interface IAppProviderState {
  isNightMode: boolean
}

const defaults = { isNightMode: false }
const AppContext = React.createContext<ICreateContext<IAppProviderState>>([
  defaults,
  () => null,
])

const AppProvider = (props: { children?: JSX.Element }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IAppProviderState>({
    isNightMode: defaults.isNightMode,
  })

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider }
```

**appStore.tsx**

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { AppContext, IAppProviderState } from "../contexts/appContext"

function useAppStore() {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(AppContext)

  function toggleNightMode(bool: boolean) {
    setState({
      isNightMode: bool,
    })
  }

  return {
    toggleNightMode,
    state,
  }
}

export { useAppStore }
```

```
// somewhere in the view I use the useAppStore hook.
// but using the method toggleNightMode, even though fires off on
// appStore.tsx - is not updating the root context state.

const { state, toggleNightMode } = useAppStore()

//..e.g

toggleNightMode(true);
```

I have removed the context and checked if the hook works with local state and it did update, sadly this is not the result I want.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. you are calling `toggleNightMode` with the wrong arguments ( you should at least see a ts error ) 2. `toggleNightMode` is ignoring the flag passed to it

Comment: thank you I updated for better clarity, even if i pass in correct args its still not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but I've created a version of what you are trying to do (not in Typescript sorry) which just toggles the value of isNightMode from true to false with a button click.

I have moved the Context and Provider code into separate files but that is just how I prefer my code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-elbakyan-i6umw

Comment: Was this any use?

Comment: doesn't do anything for me

Comment: As in you don't see the state changing on screen @evanjmg?